# Godot. Объект не подключается к сигналу

Tags: godot, signal

Godot 4.1, win 10.
Я только недавно начал кодить на годо. Простая задача - когда выбираешь какой либо элемент в MenuButton, вызывается функция со своей логикой (item_pressed) + pupupmenu передает id выбранного Item.
Выдаёт ошибку при подключении:
E 0:00:00:0431   controlsceneVest.gd:6 @ _ready(): Cannot connect to 'id_pressed': the provided callable is null.

```
extends Control

@onready var popup_menu = $MenuButton.get_popup()

func _ready():
    popup_menu.connect("id_pressed", self, "item_pressed") #<---Ошибка тут
    
func item_pressed(id):
    if id == 0: 
        _on_Item1_pressed()
    elif id == 1:
        _on_Item2_pressed()

func _on_Item1_pressed():
    print("Item1 logic")

func _on_Item2_pressed():
    print("Item2 logic")
```

Items добавил через редактор (пробовал из кода, тоже не помогло).
Памагити пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ:

```
$MenuButton.get_popup().id_pressed.connect(item_pressed)
```

К сигналам можно обращаться напрямую, как к свойствам!